# Package mfirstuc \capitalisewords doesn't work correctly

Tags: capitalization

I Declared this in the class file

```
\newcommand{\fullname}[1]{\gdef\@fullname{#1}}
```

With `\fullname{john doe}`

I am trying to get the fullname on class file. The `\MakeUperrcase{\@fullname}` works, but the `\capitalisewords` doesn't. I have tried

```
\capitalisewords\@fullname
```

and

```
\capitalisewords{\@fullname}
```

But the output is always

> JOHN DOE

instead of

> John Doe

When I checked the `\@fullname`, it prints

> john doe

Comment: please always post example code that reproduces the problem, but perhaps`\expandafter\capitalisewords\expandafter\{\@fullname}`

Comment: There's a shortcut version that does @DavidCarlisle's suggestion `\xcapitalisewords{\@fullname}`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I think having knowledge of the package commands is cheating:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle lol :-) Do you want to answer?

Comment: no feel: free your version is better (as it exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\capitalisewords` doesn't expand its argument, so you need to expand the argument first, either as David suggested in the comments:

```
\expandafter\capitalisewords\expandafter{\@fullname}
```

or use the shortcut command `\xcapitalisewords` that does the same thing:

```
\xcapitalisewords{\@fullname}
```

The reason why the argument isn't automatically expanded is because the first letter uppercasing mechanism allows for semantic markup that takes a single argument. For example:

```
\newcommand*{\strong}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1}}}
\capitalisewords{\strong{lorem} ipsum}
```

This becomes effectively

```
\strong{\MakeUppercase lorem} \MakeUppercase ipsum
```

so the semantic markup doesn't interfere with the case-change. If the argument was expanded, this instance would break as you'd end up with

```
\textcolor{\MakeUppercase red}{\textbf{lorem}} \MakeUppercase ipsum
```

(It would actually be more complicated than this if `\textcolor` was also expanded.)

If the argument starts with a control sequence that's not followed by a group, then `\capitalisewords` assumes it's a character or symbol command (such as `\aa`), so

```
\capitalisewords{\aa lorem ipsum}
```

becomes

```
\MakeUppercase \aa lorem \MakeUppercase ipsum
```

This is what's happened in your example, which is why you end up with

```
\MakeUppercase\@fullname
```